# Preencher uma div quando selecionar um item do select (formulário)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Colegas.

Tenho um select do qual os dados vem de uma base de dados. Vejam:

```
public function verSelect($tabela,$idTB,$nomeTB,$nomeSelect){

        $query = "SELECT * FROM ".$tabela;
       // echo $query;
        $sqlSelect = mysqli_query($this->conexao,$query);

        $select = "<select name='".$nomeSelect."' class='form-control' id='selecionar'>";
        $select .= "<option value='selecione'>Selecione</option>";    
        while($jmSelect = mysqli_fetch_object($sqlSelect)){
            $select .= "<option value='".$jmSelect->$idTB."'>".$jmSelect->$nomeTB."</option>";
        }
        $select .= "</select>";

        return $select;

    }
```

Legal, bacana, até aqui tudo bem. Porém preciso fazer com que ao selecionar um item desse select, apareça uma div com o conteúdo de uma outra tabela que já está relacionada. Por exemplo.: Vamos supor que eu escolha Fernando Pessoa nesse select, apareceria automaticamente a div com a palavra poeta de uma outra tabela.

Vale lembrar que a tabela já existe e está populada com as informações, só preciso da mecânica em Javascript ou jquery de como fazer isso.

Comment: Poderia colocar o html do teu projeto?

Comment: Na verdade no html só instancio o PHP do qual trago o método citado. Não tenho nada definido para trazer o resultado que desejo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisaria fazer uma requisição ajax para um script PHP com a informação que o usuário escolher no select!

Esse script vai capturar o valor que o usuário escolher no select:

```
$('#selecionar').change(function() {
    var selectedItem = $(this).val();
    // Requisição ajax
    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "/url-para-obter-dados",
       data: {item: selectedItem},
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (response) {
           // Aqui você pode montar o outro select a partir dos dados que vierem na variável response.
           console.log(response);
       }
   });
});
```

Note, onde tá escrito '/url-para-obter-dados', você substitui pela URL que você vai fazer a operação no banco de dados, no PHP você vai conseguir acessar o item selecionado usando $_GET['item']. Importante que você retorne os dados do banco como um json, para isso utilize o json_encode do PHP.

Leia mais sobre a requisição ajax aqui:
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

Comment: Perdoe-me a ignorância Junior, mas não sou muito bom em JQuery. Como eu faria para passar os valores do select para a página que fará a busca?

Comment: Então eu to atribuindo o valor do select a variável selectedItem, quando eu chegar em casa eu completo o código com um ajax pra você.

Comment: Note, onde tá escrito '/url-para-obter-dados', você substitui pela URL que você vai fazer a operação no banco de dados, no PHP você vai conseguir acessar o item selecionado usando $_GET['item']. Importante que você retorne os dados do banco como um json, para isso utilize o json_encode do PHP. Se eu soubesse a estrutura desses dados eu poderia te ajudar mais na hora de montar o select, mas você consegue ver isso pelo console do navegador apertando F12 e indo até a aba console.isso vai te ajudar também: http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: Obrigado Junior